# JAX Tridiagonal Jacobians

Tags: python, jit, jax, automatic-differentiation, tensorflow-xla

What is the most efficient implementation of a scalable autonomous tridiagonal system using `JAX`?

```
import functools as ft
import jax as jx
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax.random as jrn
import jax.lax as jlx

def make_T(m):
    # Create a psuedo-random tridiagonal Jacobian and store band
    T = jnp.zeros((3,m), dtype='f8')
    T = T.at[0, 1:  ].set(jrn.normal(jrn.PRNGKey(0), shape=(m-1,)))
    T = T.at[1,  :  ].set(jrn.normal(jrn.PRNGKey(1), shape=(m  ,)))
    T = T.at[2,  :-1].set(jrn.normal(jrn.PRNGKey(2), shape=(m-1,)))
    return T

def make_y(m):
    # Create a pseudo-random state array
    y = jrn.normal(jrn.PRNGKey(3), shape=(m  ,))
    return y

def calc_f_base(y, T):
    # Calculate the rate given the current state
    f = T[1,:]*y
    f = f.at[ 1:  ].set(f[ 1:  ]+T[0, 1:  ]*y[  :-1])
    f = f.at[  :-1].set(f[  :-1]+T[2,  :-1]*y[ 1:  ])
    return f

m = 2**22 # potentially exhausts resources
T = make_T(m)
y = make_y(m)

calc_f = ft.partial(calc_f_base, T=T)
```

Using `jax.jacrev` or `jax.jacfwd` will generate a full Jacobian which limits the size of the system.

One attempt to overcome this limitation is as follows

```
@ft.partial(jx.jit, static_argnums=(0,))
def calc_jacfwd_trid(calc_f, y):
    # Determine the Jacobian (forward-mode) tridiagonal band

    def scan_body(carry, i):
        t, T = carry
        t = t.at[i  ].set(1.0)
        
        f, dfy = jx.jvp(calc_f, (y,), (t,))
        
        T = T.at[2,i-1].set(dfy[i-1])
        T = T.at[1,i  ].set(dfy[i  ])
        T = T.at[0,i+1].set(dfy[i+1])

        t = t.at[i-1].set(0.0)

        return (t, T), None

    # Initialise
    m = y.size
    t = jnp.zeros_like(y)
    T = jnp.zeros((3,m), dtype=y.dtype)

    # Differentiate wrt y[0]
    t = t.at[0].set(1.0)
    f, dfy = jx.jvp(calc_f, (y,), (t,))
    idxs = jnp.array([1,0]), jnp.array([0,1])
    T = T.at[idxs].set(dfy[0:2])

    # Differentiate wrt y[1:-1]
    (t, T), empty = jlx.scan(scan_body, (t,T), jnp.arange(1,m-1))

    # Differentiate wrt y[-1]
    t = t.at[m-2:].set(jnp.array([0.0,1.0]))
    f, dfy = jx.jvp(calc_f, (y,), (t,))
    idxs = jnp.array([2,1]), jnp.array([m-2,m-1])
    T = T.at[idxs].set(dfy[-2:])

    return T
```

which permits

```
T = jacfwd_trid(calc_f, y)

df = jrn.normal(jrn.PRNGKey(4), shape=y.shape)
dx = jlx.linalg.tridiagonal_solve(*T,df[:,None]).flatten()
```

Is there a better approach and/or can the time complexity of `calc_jacfwd_trid` be reduced further?

**EDIT**
The following implementation is more compact, but run times are slightly slower

```
@ft.partial(jx.jit, static_argnums=(0,))
def calc_jacfwd_trid_map(calc_f, y):
    # Determine the Jacobian (forward-mode) tridiagonal band with lax map

    def map_body(i, t):

        t = t.at[i-1].set(0.0)
        
        f, dfy = jx.jvp(calc_f, (y,), (t,))

        im1 = jnp.where(i > 0, i-1, 0)
        Ti = jlx.dynamic_slice(dfy, (im1,), (3,))
        Ti = jnp.where(i >   0, Ti, jnp.roll(Ti, shift=+1))
        Ti = jnp.where(i < m-1, Ti, jnp.roll(Ti, shift=-1))

        t = t.at[i  ].set(1.0)

        return Ti

    # Initialise
    m = y.size
    t = jnp.zeros_like(y)

    # Differentiate wrt y[:]
    T = jlx.map(lambda i : map_body(i, t=t), jnp.arange(m))

    # Correct the orientation of T
    T = T.transpose()
    T = jnp.flip(T, axis=0)
    T = T.at[0,:].set(jnp.roll(T[0,:], shift=+1))
    T = T.at[2,:].set(jnp.roll(T[2,:], shift=-1))

    return T
```

Comment: The key to a matrix-free version of this is to use tangents that are nonlinear in terms of index. Two immediate options come to mind: polynomials and trigonometric functions. The choice may be guided by the numerical stability of the reconstruction. Not sure if the speed difference between constructing polynomials and trigonometric tangents will be consequential.